# Without calculating limit directly show that it is equal to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{1}{3^n}=0$$
I am not really sure what it means by "without calculating limit" and I don't really have ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\left(1+\dfrac 1 n\right)^n < e \,\,$so $\left(1+\dfrac 1 n\right)^{n^2} < e^n$
so $\left(1+\dfrac 1 n\right)^{n^2} \dfrac 1{3^n} < \dfrac{e^n}{3^n}
= \left(\dfrac e 3 \right)^n \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy test for the series we have :

$$\sqrt[n]{(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2}\frac{1}{3^n}}=(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n}\frac{1}{3}\sim_\infty \frac{e}{3}<1$$
hence the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2}\frac{1}{3^n}$$
is convergent and then the general term is convergent to $0$.

Comment: There is no need to appeal to series. Cauchy's test already tells $a_n\to 0$. But it tells it goes to zero faster than a geometric, which gives the series converges, which is just a plus.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff what I know the Cauchy test it applies to the series isn't it? see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: cute approach (+1)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane There is nothing wrong with the answer, I was simply pointing out that the test says $a_n<\alpha^n$ for some $0<\alpha <1$; so $a_n\to 0$. That $\sum a_n$ exists is an extra, because it is dominated by $\sum \alpha^n$.

Comment: This looks quite fine to me!